# How to configure a specific subdirectory and build out of tree?

Tags: makefile, cmake, llvm, libc++

I'm trying to build libc++ with LLVM/Clang. I'm running onto a couple of problems. First, though [LLVM/Clang](http://llvm.org/docs/LLVMBuild.html) supports both Makefiles and Cmake, the libc++ project abandoned Makefile support. So I'm stuck with Cmake for this particular component. Second, LLVM/Clang build infrastructure does not configure libc++, so its not *à la carte* like I thought. So I need to turn some knobs to make things work.

Here's what the tree looks like I'm working with. Sources are under `llvm` (in-tree), while artifacts are under `build` (out-of-tree).

```
Working directory
  |
  +- build (artifacts and staging)
  |
  +- llvm (source tree)
     |
     +- tools
     |  |
     |  +- Compiler Front End (Clang)
     |
     +- projects
        |
        +- Compiler RT
        |
        +- libcxx
        |
        +- libcxx ABI
```

I need to run Cmake and tell it to configure what's in `llvm/projects/libcxx`, and tell Cmake to generate Makefiles that build and stage into the appropriate directory under `build`. Everything else can use Makefiles. (Its unclear to me what the "appropriate directory" is since the project's documentation does not tell me. I'll cross that bridge next, but I'd like to start with `build`).

I looked at the [Cmake man pages](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html), and I can't find a way to specify those simple requirements. For example, I can find `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `CMAKE_Fortran_MODDIR_FLAG`, but I don't see where I can specify that everything goes to `build`. (Configure and Makefiles are pretty easy - I `cd` into the directory and run `configure`; or I just say `make -f llvm/projects/libcxx/Makefile` and things just work).

How do I tell Cmake to configure what's in `llvm/projects/libcxx`, and how do I tell it to generate Makefiles that specify `build` as the build and output directory?

Comment: Whats wrong with `cd build && cmake ../llvm && make`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure subdirectory because parent `CMakeLists.txt` might contain necessary configuration code for subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt`.

What you can do is to configure everything, but run `make` only for `libcxx`:

```
cd build/projects/libcxx && make
```

This would build libcxx and all it's dependencies, but stuff from `tools`, for instance, wouldn't be built.